# Where is the binary file that lets me change from Homestead to Classic in Parity? Does changing the "config.full.toml" do the trick?

Tags: nodes, parity, ethereum-classic

I am trying to run an ethereum classic node on parity so that I can sell my classic. I see the doc that says: https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/Ethereum-Classic

The only problem is after I "git clone https://github.com/ethcore/parity", I have no Idea which folder is considered the binary.

In Home->parity->parity->cli, I found config.full.toml, which when I open has: chain = "Homestead".

I changed that to: chain = "classic"

1)I am not sure if that worked, I am downloading now, but in the terminal, in the beginning, it says "Configured for Frontier/Homestead". How can I determine if I am downloading classic early on in the chain download process?

2) Which folder contains the actual binary file and what is its name?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to sync with the classic chain is to clear your current Parity blockchain, then run parity with the `--chain classic` parameter:

```
parity --chain classic
```

---

### Updated Responding To Comment Below

There are instructions to download and install the Parity binaries for Ubuntu, Mac OS/X and Windows https://ethcore.io/parity.html.

Comment: Ok, could you provide a link to how to do that?

Comment: Link at the bottom of my answer. What operating system are you running?